# Recursividad - Promedio de los dígitos de un numero (con restricciones)

Tags: c

Tengo una duda con mi código. Son ejercicios básicos de *recursividad*, pero no logro poder solucionarlo.
Dejo la consigna:

*Escribir una función que obtenga el número promedio de un numero natural N. Definimos como el
número promedio de N natural, al número que se obtiene de sumar sus dígitos impares y restar sus
dígitos pares.
numPromedio(318547) → 4*

```
//Resolución 1
#include <stdio.h>

int numeroPromedio(int n);
int numeroPromedio1(int n, int acumuladorImapares, int acumuladorPares);


int main(){
  int number;

  printf("Ingrese numero: "); scanf("%d", &number);

  printf("El promedio del numero ingresado es: %d\n", numeroPromedio(number));

  return 0;
}

int numeroPromedio(int n){
  return numeroPromedio1(n, 0, 0); //numero, acumulador de imapares, acumulador de pares
}

int numeroPromedio1(int n, int acumuladorImapares, int acumuladorPares){

  if(n==0)
    return acumuladorImapares-acumuladorPares;
  else{
    if((n%10)%2 != 0) return numeroPromedio1(n/10, acumuladorImapares+n%10, acumuladorPares);
    else return numeroPromedio1(n/10, acumuladorImapares, acumuladorPares+n%10);
  }
}
```

---

```
//Resolución 2

#include <stdio.h>

int numeroPromedio(int n);

int main(){
    int number;

    printf("Ingrese numero: "); scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("El promedio de los digitos del numero ingresado es: %d\n", numeroPromedio(number));


    return 0;
}


int numeroPromedio(int n){

    if(n==0) return 0;
    else{
        if((n%10)%2 != 0) return numeroPromedio(n/10) + n%10;
        else return numeroPromedio(n/10) - n%10;
    }

}
```

---

Dos cuestiones:

1) El código funciona para el ejemplo (318547) -> 4, pero cuando ingreso por ejemplo (223) -> -1 y NO debería devolver -1, sino, 2. O sea el cociente ENTERO de operar (2+2+3)/3= 2.

Más claro, sin las restricciones de la consiga lo saco al ejercicio, pero me pregunto si hay alguna forma de que funcione respetando que se SUMEN DIGITOS IMPARES, y luego a estos se le RESTEN LOS DIGITOS PARES.

2) Y, la segunda pregunta no tan importante como la anterior pero me serviría de consejo. ¿A cual de las dos soluciones la ven mas clara de leer?(Obviamente sacando la cuestión de que no funciona en determinados casos, como aclare mas arriba!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El código funciona para el ejemplo (318547) -> 4, pero cuando ingreso
>   por ejemplo (223) -> -1 y NO debería devolver -1, sino, 2. O sea el
>   cociente ENTERO de operar (2+2+3)/3= 2.

El enunciado dice claramente *"sumar sus dígitos impares y restar sus dígitos pares"*. No dice nada acerca de que haya que dividir en ningún sitio. En el caso de 223 tenemos dos dígitos pares (que se restan) y un dígito impar (que se suma), luego 3-2-2=-1 e indica que el código funciona según la especificación dada.

Por otro lado, en cuanto a lo que hablas de claridad, yo pienso que la segunda solución es más clara: menos funciones, menos código y encima éste no es ofuscado... pero aún se podría mejorar en este aspecto:

```
int numeroPromedio(int n){
  if(n==0) return 0;

  int promedio = numeroPromedio(n/10);
  int digito = n%10;

  if(digito%2 != 0)
    promedio += digito;
  else
    promedio -= digito;

  return promedio;
}
```

O incluso, si te gustan los if ternarios:

```
int numeroPromedio(int n){
  if(n==0) return 0;

  int promedio = numeroPromedio(n/10);
  int digito = n%10;

  return (digito%2)? (promedio - digito) : (promedio + digito);
}
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

**Otra solución sería:**

```
char numero[20];
int solucion;
scanf("%s", numero); //leer numero
solucion = numPromedio(numero);
```

**Definicion de la función:**

```
int numPromedio(char *num){ // tam es el tamano del vector - 1

      if(*num == '\0')
         return 0;
      if( (*num - 48) % 2 ) // transformación a entero según tabla ASCII
         return numPromedio( num + 1 ) - (*num - 48); // acumula la suma de los pares
      else
         return numPromedio(num + 1) + (*num - 48); // acumula la suma de los impares

}
```

**Explicación:** 
La función recorre todos los dígitos desde 0 hasta n, de modo que si se encuentra un dígito par lo va acumulando de forma negativa, o si es impar de forma positiva. Y en el momento que llegue al final de la cadena, retorna cero.

En otras palabras: va restando los impares y sumando los pares a medida que va iterando cada numero.